# How to open a photo in picasa 3?

Tags: 12.10, wine

I downloaded picasa 3 using wine for my ubuntu 12.10 and installed. The problem is, I'm unable to open my photo using picasa. I'm trying "open with" with mouse right-click on the file but unable to find the picasa option there.

How to get it??

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a launcher for it.

To do so, use a tool similar to `alacarte`. Search for your app `*.exe` and write `wine` in front of it.

So that the command in your new launcher is similar to:

```
wine /path/to/my/exe/file.exe
```

Once you create a desktop file, it will appear in the open with... menu.